# ruby code to direct all users to a particular location instead of multiple locations and delete duplicates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I am having a User model and a Location Model. Each user belongs to a particular location in the Location model.

I am having duplicate locations in the Location table.
and User belongs to Location.
how can i remove duplicate rows in the location table and keep one row and make all users belong to that single row using ruby. Both the tables are connected through location_ID attribute.

I tried to do this through migration:

```
 def dedupe(model, *key_attrs)
     model.select(key_attrs).group(key_attrs).having('count(*) > 1').each { |duplicates|
       dup_rows = model.where(duplicates.attributes.slice(key_attrs)).to_a
        # the first one we want to keep right?
        first_one = dup_rows.shift #stored the first one
        dup_rows.each{ |double| double.destroy } # duplicates can now be destroyed
     }
  end
```

But there is foreign key constraint of User not letting the migration to run. How can I achieve this?

Current Models are :

```
User
user_id   name  location_id
1         tim     1
2         adam    2
3         Joy     3

Location
location_id  name
1            NewYork
2            NewYork
3            NewYork
```

> Expected Ouput:

```
User
user_id   name  location_id
1         tim     1
2         adam    1
3         Joy     1

Location
location_id  name
1            NewYork
```

Comment: Could you show the expected output from your query?

Comment: Does it matter if you keep the first or last instance? Do you only care about uniqueness based on `user_id` and `location`?

Comment: I have Edited my question. please refer to it. I want to remove duplicates and make users having same location to point to only one record in Location table. I want to achieve this through migration using ruby

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way:

1)First Update all entries with location first entry in location table using

```
 User.joins(:location).update_all("location_id = select id from locations as l2 where l2.name = locations.name limit 1")
```

Note: you can also use order by id here if sub query not return first entry from table.

2)Destroy All entries from location table excluding first entry-

Before this make sure all your data get updated with first entry in location table properly means first id of repeated location is updated or not. because after deletion it is not possible to recover your data again. then just destroy all your repeated entries excluding first entry using

```
Location.where("id not in (?)", Location.select("min(id) as id").group("name").map(&:id)).destroy_all
```

Comment: @Abhishek i have given you a solution on basis of your table structure and your earlier question. In your migration what you are trying to do can you please elaborate??

Comment: Through my migration i want to delete all duplicates locations having duplicate names in the location table and keep the first one. Then I want to make all users belonging to that location to point to the one which is kept after deleting the duplicates.  i was unable to express earlier .If still not clear please  do tell me. I am stuck at this since two days :/

Comment: @Abhishek have you tried my response?? because i am doing same with sql queries

Comment: @Abhishek you are attached tag of `mysql` error showing you are using `PG`. PG not support to select other column than group column

Comment: Yepp I am using PG. So what should i do know? I mean is there any query to support my problem?

Comment: @Abhishek i have change this group query you can check it now.

Comment: Vishal . I am getting this error : "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "locations"
LINE 1: ... =(select id from locations as l2 where l2.name = locations....
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "l2". "
after modifying..

Answer (score 0):

Kinda ugly, but you can use a subquery:

First, grab the first occurrence of all records which are duplicates;

```
original_duplicate_locations = Location.select("MIN(id) AS id, name, user_id").group(:name, :user_id).having("COUNT(id) > 1")
```

The extra duplicates are defined as locations having the same `name`, and `user_id` but not the same `id`:

```
duplicates_not_including_originals = Location.joins("JOIN (#{duplicates.to_sql}) dupes ON locations.name = dupes.name AND locations.user_id = dupes.user_id AND locations.id <> dupes.id")
```